# IOS-xcode 7,debug external library

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I have an IOS project that has an external lib(there is a file with 'a' extension in the external libs folder).the library is anoter project which I made.
When I try to debug the source code of the library the breakpoints not get hited.
Is it possible to debug an external lib without import the source files to the main project?

Comment: Was the library built with debug information?

Comment: I think so..Can you tell me how to check this?I'm kinda new to it. @trojanfoe

Comment: I think @trojanfoe refers to Build Settings > Build options > Debug information format. The value must be "Dwarf with dSym file". Check the "Strip debug symbols during copy", too

Comment: Yes this is the format.

Comment: Actually you don't want a dsym file as that means you need to track it.  You want the other one where the debug information is put into the object files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by this check the lib build fromat and add it to the main project by this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/Adding_a_Framework.html)